# Back button in modal NavigationPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My application presents a page, wrapped within a NavigationPage as a modal as part of a workflow process within the app.

I would like to add a platform specific "Back" button (UWP back arrow in title bar, "Back" text in iOS), i.e. the normal navigation behaviour you would see if an additional page was pushed on to the stack, which closes the modal and returns to the main application page.

Can this be done?

Comment: usually if you are displaying a modal, you would want to use a "Close" or "Done" button, not a back button

Comment: For that you need to create custom navigation bar with back arrow icon and title in XAML design of that particular page.